# Expand a Sequence grouped by keys into a list of ungrouped sequences with keys attached in Scala

Tags: scala, sequence, flatten

I have the following object in Scala:

```
List[(String,Map[String, Seq[(Int, Double)]])]
```

And I would like to convert it into a sequence of individual rows where each row of the sequence has 4 terms: `(String,String,Int,Double)`.

For instance, if I had the following data:

```
List(
  ("SuperGroup1", Map("SubGroup1" -> Seq((17,24.1),(38,39.2)))),
  ("SuperGroup1", Map("SubGroup2" -> Seq((135,302.3),(938,887.4))))
)
```

I want to turn it into:

```
Seq(
  ("SuperGroup1","SubGroup1",17,24.1),
  ("SuperGroup1","SubGroup1",38,39.2),
  ("SuperGroup1","SubGroup2",135,302.3),
  ("SuperGroup1","SubGroup2",938,887.4)
)
```

I figure you can use `flatMap` or something like that, but I am not exactly sure how that would work. I see that RDDs have a function called `flatMapValues`, but what about for just a standard list/map combination like I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
val x = List(
  ("SuperGroup1",Map("SubGroup1" -> Seq((17,24.1),(38,39.2)))),
  ("SuperGroup1",Map("SubGroup2" -> Seq((135,302.3),(938,887.4))))
)
```

you obtain the list that you want from

```
for ((s, m) <- x; (k, vs) <- m; (i, f) <- vs) yield (s, k, i, f)
```

Result:

```
List(
  (SuperGroup1,SubGroup1,17,24.1),
  (SuperGroup1,SubGroup1,38,39.2),
  (SuperGroup1,SubGroup2,135,302.3),
  (SuperGroup1,SubGroup2,938,887.4)
)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, thanks. I see from your response and the other posted here that my question required a not very obvious solution. I am surprised there isn't a more standardized way to expand out a map and a sequence .

Comment: @EliSquared I'm not sure what you mean by "not obvious". It's just nested iteration over everything that is iterable, and writing down every value that is not iterable. Seems pretty obvious to me.

Comment: @EliSquared `x` is iterable, so you iterate over it. `s` is not iterable, so you add it to the tuple. `m` is iterable, so you iterate over it. `k` is not iterable, so you add it to the tuple. `vs` is iterable, so you iterate over it. `i` and `f` are both not iterable, so you add them to the tuple. Done. Fits into a nice short one-liner too. Not too bad for three nested loops, essentially.

Comment: Well RDDs have the `flatMapValues` function, so I figured there would be a comparable algorithm like that which could easily be applied, to both the `Map` and the `Tuple` data structures.

Comment: @EliSquared Ah, the `flatMapValues` thingie... I guess it came from the PairRDD, which in turn was inherited from Hadoops focus on pairs / tuples. The pair-specific operations are traditionally not in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Given the types you have and the following input:

```
val input = Seq(
  ("SuperGroup1", Map("SubGroup1" -> Seq(((17,24.1),(38,39.2))))),
  ("SuperGroup1", Map("SubGroup2" -> Seq(((135,302.3),(938,887.4)))))
)
```

This would transform your input into the form you expect

```
input.flatMap { superGroupBox =>
  superGroupBox._2.toSeq.flatMap { subGroupBox =>
    subGroupBox._2.flatMap(x => Seq(x._1, x._2).map(numericTuple => (superGroupBox._1, subGroupBox._1, numericTuple._1, numericTuple._2)))
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't have the specified type. Too many unnecessary parentheses. I fixed the question so that the previously invalid expression becomes valid and has the specified type.